# Windows 8 metro app button behavior of foreground and background color

Tags: button, windows-8

In windows 8 metro apps I added a button using xaml as follows

```
<Button Foreground="#FFF51A1A" Background="#FFEAE23A" BorderBrush="White" 
Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="HELLO"/>
```

and the same button I tried to add dynamically as below

```
        Button shelfButton = new Button();

        shelfButton.Content = "HELLO";
        shelfButton.Foreground = FFF51A1A;
        shelfButton.Background = FFEAE23A;

        shelfButton.Height = 100;
        shelfButton.Width = 100;

        Grid.Children.Add(shelfButton);
```

The behavior of buttons in regard to foreground and background colors is different. Why is this like this ? and 
How to have similar behavior as xaml even when adding buttons dynamically.

Comment: this cant be the real code, as the you have to set foreground and background to a brush. Alos your numbers are not hexadecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get equivalent behavior, you can set the Foreground and Background of your shelfButton to a SolidColorBrush in your code.  There is a HEX ("#FFF51A1A") to SolidColorBrush converter at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/befe7695-9458-4abb-b867-619df52b8183.